# Macbook Mid2014 El Capitan Fan stop working from time to time?

Tags: macbook, fan, speedfan

I did a fresh installation with thumb drive. The fan works fine on restart, but suddenly stops after a while. I tried resetting SCM but not working.
I also tried to use scmFanControl, not working as well.

What should I do?

Comment: MacBook fans are only supposed to run as needed when the system temperature gets above a threshold. It could be that El Capitan is running your system more efficiently, so the fans don't need to come on as often. I only hear my fan running if I'm doing a compile or 3D gaming or running crappy Flash video/animations.

Comment: @Spiff no it's not the case, I can monitor the fan using SCM, its lowest rpm would be around 1300, but my fan stops completely from time to time. Not mentioning it sometimes stops when I'm watching videos with flash (which is very performance demanding. And the most annoying thing is that because fan stops, CPU clock will be limited and the entire system got slowed like crap.

Comment: So, do you have an XY problem in your question? I think the real thing you want to fix is the system slowness. Making the fans spin more often is not really the goal, is it?

Comment: @Spiff omg...... NO! I'm 99% sure it's the fan-stop causing the system slow. I've said the fan sometimes stops even when it's running at a high speed (such as watching video); it stops suddenly.